# How are PowerShell Modules (particularly PSReadline) loaded automatically in V5?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, powershell-5.0, psreadline

I recently installed Windows 10, which includes V5 of PowerShell, or `5.1.14393.206` to be exact (`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`).

On new computers I install [PSReadline](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine).  However, Windows 10 comes with it already installed.

My question is, how is PSReadline loading automatically, when there is no profile to import it, (or call a command from it)?

As proof, I ran this code:

```
$PROFILE | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % {
    $path = $PROFILE.$($_.Name);
    $exists = Test-Path $path;
    [pscustomobject]@{ Path = $path; Exists = $exists }
}
```

To get this:

```
Path                                                                        Exists
----                                                                        ------
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1                       False
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1  False
C:\Users\tahir\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1                       False
C:\Users\tahir\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1  False
```

I have gone through all of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23942543/288393:

- No call to `Import-Module` for PSReadline is made because there are no profiles to call it.
- No commands within PSReadline module are made because, as before, there are no profiles to call it.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2016-11-29%7D/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHost.cs#L1598

Comment: @PetSerAl - am I right in thinking that the loading of PSReadline is hard-coded into PowerShell's source code?

Comment: Yes, it is hard-coded for PowerShell default console host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is special code in the console host to load PSReadline if the process is interactive. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/24f3b75549428bead9b2a0ae00d762fe931e7e5e/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHost.cs#L1594).

Comment: (I acknowledge that it is the same answer as PetSerAl's.)

Answer (score 1):

PSReadline is located in a pre-defined module folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`, because it's here PowerShell's automatic cmdlet discovery and module loading process will pick the module up and load it when any functions within it are called. That process [added in PS v3](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-v3-autoloading-modules).

Comment: Although what you say about automatic cmdlet discovery is true, this is not how PSReadline is automatically loaded.